# Timeout on SQL Server Delete Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am using the following code:

```
'item being 14
mySQLdel = "DELETE FROM table WHERE ID= " & item
response.write "<p>SQL Command: " & mySQLdel & "</p>"
myConn.Execute(mySQLdel)
```

Whether the record with the id 14 exists or not, I am getting:

> DELETE FROM table WHERE ID=14
>
> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e31'
>
> Query timeout expired
>
> /index.asp, line 58

Line 58 being:

```
myConn.Execute(mySQLdel)
```

The equivalent command is fine working on another table, so I assume that it is something to do with permissions, although can't for the life of me work out what.

When I run the same SQL in SQL Management Studio, the query executes almost instantly.

Here is the create script which was requested below:

```
USE [user1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tablename](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [var1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [var2] [int] NULL,
    [var3] [int] NULL,
    [var4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [datecreated] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

`sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` shows

```
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| waiting_task_address | session_id | exec_context_id | wait_duration_ms | wait_type | resou‌​rce_address | blocking_task_address | blocking_session_id | blocking_exec_context_id |                                      re‌​source_description                                      |  |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| 0x00000000041F7288   |         63 |               0 |             7139 | LCK_M_U   | 0x00000000869F2C40 | NULL                  |                  69 | NULL                     | ridlock fileid=1 pageid=214 dbid=61 id=lock847e0b00 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057594039435264  |  |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that your exact query or are you using parameterised queries? If it isn't your exact query please post the actual query and the table definition including indexes.

Comment: This might seem like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but could you make your delete command into a stored procedure.  Also, have you tried connecting via Native Client rather than SQLOLEDB? http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Have edited to show exact query.
How do I show table definition? Have right clicked on table and then properties, but not really sure what it is helpful for you to see there.

Comment: Right click the table and script out the `CREATE` and add it to your question.

Comment: I have added table definition to the original question

Comment: Any triggers on the table? When the web app query is running does `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks WHERE session_id > 50` return anything?

Comment: Here is what i get when I run that:
waiting_task_address session_id exec_context_id wait_duration_ms wait_type resource_address blocking_task_address blocking_session_id blocking_exec_context_id resource_description
0x00000000041F7288 63 0 7139 LCK_M_U 0x00000000869F2C40 NULL 69 NULL ridlock fileid=1 pageid=214 dbid=61 id=lock847e0b00 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057594039435264

Comment: Well that looks like you are getting blocked waiting for a lock on a heap.

Comment: meaning? What is the solution?

Comment: @john I have just created a stored procedure and looks like it is going to time out also.

Comment: Difficult to know why the same query is getting blocked from the web app but not SSMS. Is there any trigger on the table? if not must be a different execution plan I assume. What indexes are on the table? And is it referenced by any foreign keys?

Comment: Also what is `session_id = 69`? That looks like it might be an idle uncommitted transaction. This isn't your SSMS window is it?

Comment: Interestingly, when I call the stored procedure from an ASP script rather than SQL SMS, it works perfectly. Not sure what that means, but there's my solution for now I guess.
THIS WAS ONLY TEMPORARILY. NOW AS BEFORE.

Comment: Yes Martin, that is from my SSMS window.

Comment: @user2029763 - If you close the SSMS window do you see a warning about uncommitted transactions?

Comment: I was in the middle of debugging, so it asked me if I wanted to stop debuggin. I said yes and then it let me close ssms without any further messages.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things that can cause sql server to take a longer than expected to do something.  When you are doing a delete it might be cascading into other tables for example.  What you will need to do is simply increase the timeout on the command before you execute it.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; //no timeout
cmd.CommandText = "delete from foo;";
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why "When I run the same SQL in SQL Management Studio, the query executes almost instantly."

Comment: He also didnt mention if he was talking about local vs a remote system.  Like I said, there are many many things that can cause sql server to take longer than expected, memory pressure, io pressure, other processes, network latency, etc.

Comment: None of those (except possibly network latency) would explain a difference between the same query executed locally and remote. And network traffic for a typical simple `delete` command would be minimal.

Comment: The db is on the same server and the webserver. i am viewing locally in my browser.

Comment: @user2029763 - And are you finding that this is consistently repeatable? That in SSMS it runs instantly and in the web app it times out?

Answer (score 0):

Alright...I must eat humble pie...

What I was doing was calling a record from table1 and then doing something like:

```
if not myRS.eof then
    delete from table1
end if
```

Once I changed the code, all is good...